# Bond energy and s-character

Tags: bond, orbitals, hybridization

While studying the basics of chemical bonding, I've often come across the following statements:
1. The bond energy increases with the increase in the s-character in a hybrid orbital, i.e sp3 sp2-sp2, and so on.

I can't seem to correlate the two. If a hybrid has a higher bond energy, shouldn't it also form stronger bonds?

Answer (score 5):

Let us start with the following most important part of the [IUPAC definition for the bond energy](http://goldbook.iupac.org/B00701.html).

> **bond energy (mean bond energy)**
>
> The average value of the gas-phase bond dissociation energies (usually
>   at a temperature of 298 K) for all bonds of the same type within the
>   same chemical species.

I think it should be immediately clear now that the *higher* a bond energy is, the *stronger* is the bond, so that there is no any contradiction in a bond energy increase with the increase of the $\mathrm{s}$-character in hybrid $\mathrm{sp}^n$-orbitals.

Indeed, $\mathrm{2s}$-orbitals are lower in energy that the $\mathrm{2p}$ ones, and thus, the more $\mathrm{s}$-character a hybrid orbital has, the lower is its energy: $E_{\mathrm{sp}} < E_{\mathrm{sp^2}} < E_{\mathrm{sp^3}}$. The lower an atomic or hybrid orbital energy is, the lower is the energy of a molecular orbital in formation of which it participates, $E_{\sigma_\mathrm{sp}} < E_{\sigma_\mathrm{sp^2}} < E_{\sigma_\mathrm{sp^3}}$, and consequently, the higher is the corresponding bond dissociation energy, as well as, the average of them, i.e. the bond energy. So, the bond energy indeed increases as the s-character grows, say $E_{\ce{C(\mathrm{sp})-C(\mathrm{sp})}} > E_{\ce{C(\mathrm{sp^2})-C(\mathrm{sp^2})}} > E_{\ce{C(\mathrm{sp^3})-C(\mathrm{sp^3})}}$.

Below is the MO diagram for $\sigma$ $\ce{C-C}$ bond between two $\mathrm{sp}$-, two $\mathrm{sp^2}$-, and two $\mathrm{sp^3}$-hydridized $\ce{C}$ atoms that illustrates the logic above.
[image]

Comment: @DHMO: if the sp hybrid orbital is stronger than the sp3 orbital, why is the sp-sp bond weaker than the sp3-sp3 bond?

Comment: @Kōhai, first note that orbitals aren't stronger/weaker relative to each other, but rather, they are lower/higher in energy. Now, the lower a bonding orbital is, the stronger is the corresponding bond. Finally, who  told you that $\ce{C(\mathrm{sp})-C(\mathrm{sp})}$ bond is weaker than the $\ce{C(\mathrm{sp^3})-C(\mathrm{sp^3})}$ one?

Comment: A quick Google search results in 347–356 kJ/mol for bond-dissociation energy (at 298 K) for $\sigma$ $\ce{C(\mathrm{sp})-C(\mathrm{sp})}$ bond in alkanes and 837-839 kJ/mol for the triple bond in alkynes, out of which the $\sigma$ $\ce{C(\mathrm{sp^3})-C(\mathrm{sp^3})}$ bond contributes 369 kJ/mol.

Comment: Okay, just to ensure that I've understood this correctly, lower the hybrid orbital energy, higher is the dissociation energy of the bond it forms, right? I think I messed up between the energy and the bond energy.

Comment: @Kōhai, yes, the lower a bonding orbital is, the more energy is required to break the bond. In our case the bonding orbital is formed from a hybrid orbital of C atom and some orbital of another atom X. And for a given orbital of atom X, the lower the hybrid orbital of C atom is, the lower a bonding orbital will be. I think I can try to draw this...